# Discord.py ban command

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!BAN'):
        if "449706643710541824" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            await
```

I have the base setup so only admins can ban. I want to make the ban command, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you actually try using the [ban](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.ban) command in some way in your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My ban command i got for my bot is , obviously dont keep the comment out for the ban part, I just put that there when i didn't know how to lock it to roles

```py
#bans a user with a reason
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Keyblade Master","Foretellers")
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("You cannot ban yourself")
        return
    if reason == None:
        reason = "For being a jerk!"
    message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    # await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is banned!")
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to ban for a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```py
import discord #Imports the discord module.
from discord.ext import commands #Imports discord extensions.

#The below code verifies the "client".
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='pb?')
#The below code stores the token.
token = "Your token"

'''
The below code displays if you have any errors publicly. This is useful if you don't want to display them in your output shell.
'''
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please pass in all requirements :rolling_eyes:.')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You dont have all the requirements :angry:")

#The below code bans player.
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)

#The below code unbans player.
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return

#The below code runs the bot.
client.run(token)
```

I hope this helps, good luck on your bot!

Comment: I would always recommend advising to store tokens in the main file of a program. op might accidentally share not knowing the risks

Comment: @Evan Almost accidentally did this once, but Discord detected a bot token in the text and stopped me from sending it. Good job Discord devs!!

Answer (score 2):

This is the best one

```
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, reason=None):
    """Bans a user"""
    if reason == None:
        await ctx.send(f"Woah {ctx.author.mention}, Make sure you provide a reason!")
    else:
        messageok = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
        await member.send(messageok)
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

Comment: Please add some details for your answer rather than simply posting a code snippet without context.

Comment: Ok. I will do that next time!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use `discord.ext.commands` to make commands, it's easier to use. The function to ban is [`discord.Client.ban(member, delete_message_days = 1)`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.ban). This is an example using `discord.ext.commands`:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def ban(member: discord.Member, days: int = 1):
    if "449706643710541824" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        await bot.ban(member, days)
    else:
        await bot.say("You don't have permission to use this command.")

bot.run("<TOKEN>")
```

Answer (score 1):

A ban command? It's actually very easy!

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.ban(reason=reason)
        ban = discord.Embed(title=f":boom: Banned {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=ban)
        await user.send(embed=ban)
```

if you know kick you just need to change the `user.kick` into a `user.ban` because `user.kick` will kick a member so that means `user.ban` will ban a member.

Answer (score 1):

According to Discord Official Documentation:-

```py
@bot.command(name="ban", help="command to ban user")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def _ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    """ command to ban user. Check !help ban """
    try:
        await member.ban(reason=reason)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.name} has been banned from server'
                               f'Reason: {reason}')
    except Exception:
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Bot doesn't have enough permission to ban someone. Upgrade the Permissions")


@bot.command(name="unban", help="command to unban user")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def _unban(ctx, *, member_id: int):
    """ command to unban user. check !help unban """
    await ctx.guild.unban(discord.Object(id=member_id))
    await ctx.send(f"Unban {member_id}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member :  discord.Member, *,reason=None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("You cannot ban yourself")
        return
    if reason == None:
        reason = "For being a jerk!"
    message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} is banned!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a ban command I use and it works perfectly fine for me. You have full permission to use the whole thing if you'd like.

```
async def ban(self, ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    author = ctx.message.author
    if author.guild_permissions.administrator == False:
        embed4=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.red(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), title="Missing Permissions!", description="You don't have the required permissions to use this command!")
        message1 = await ctx.send(embed=embed4)    
        sleeper=5
        await asyncio.sleep(sleeper) 
        await message1.delete()
        return  
    if member.guild_permissions.administrator and member != None:
        embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.red(), title="Administrator", description="This user is an administrator and is not allowed to be banned.")
        message2 = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        sleeper=5
        await asyncio.sleep(sleeper)
        await message2.delete()
        return
    if reason == None:
        embed1=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.red(), title="Reason Required!", description="You must enter a reason to ban this member.")    
        message3 = ctx.send(embed=embed1)
        sleeper=5
        await asyncio.sleep(sleeper)
        await message3.delete()
        return
    else:
        guild = ctx.guild
        await member.ban()
        embed2=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.green(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), title="Member Banned", description=f"Banned: {member.mention}\n Moderator: **{author}** \n Reason: **{reason}**")
        embed3=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.green(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), title=f"You've been banned from **{guild}**!", description=f"Target: {member.mention}\nModerator: **{author.mention}** \n Reason: **{reason}**")
        message4 = await ctx.send(embed=embed2)
        message5 = await ctx.send("✔ User has been notified.")
        sleeper=5
        await asyncio.sleep(sleeper)
        await message4.delete()
        await message5.delete()
        await member.send(embed=embed3)
```

Comment: The question was about banning, not kicking.

Comment: My sincerest apologize! I wasn't paying much attention, so I made a huge mistake. I just edited to match. Once again, sorry!