# Python Discord.py Ban/Kick Command

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

i want to make a simple ban, unban and kick command but i couldn't figure it out.

i tried this: [Discord.py ban command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569780/discord-py-ban-command) but it doesn't work.

i don't have any error. and this is how i use on discord <!kick @dcname>

my code:

```
@client.command
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(message, member:discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await message.send(f"{member} sunucudan atıldı.")
```

Comment: Did you go through the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

Comment: @Ayb009 yes but i cant understand my english is not enough, translate also bad :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kick**:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} kicked from the server.")
```

- **@has_permissions(kick_members=True)** decorator ensures that the user calling the command has the permission to **kick** members.
- The **ctx** parameter represents the context of the command, such as the channel it was invoked in.
- The **"*"** is used with the reason parameter to allow the user to provide a reason for the action being taken. This allows the user to provide a string of any length as the reason, which is then passed as an argument to the function.
- The **await member.kick(reason=reason)** kicks the member from the server.

**Ban**:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} banned from the server.")
```

- **@has_permissions(ban_members=True)** decorator ensures that the user calling the command has the permission to **ban** members.
- The **ctx** parameter represents the context of the command, such as the channel it was invoked in.
- The **"*"** is used with the reason parameter to allow the user to provide a reason for the action being taken. This allows the user to provide a string of any length as the reason, which is then passed as an argument to the function.
- The **await member.ban(reason=reason)** bans the member from the server.

**Unban**:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: discord.User, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.guild.unban(member, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} unbanned.")
```

- **@has_permissions(ban_members=True)** decorator work the same way as in the ban command.
- The **ctx** parameter represents the context of the command, such as the channel it was invoked in.
- The **"*"** is used with the member parameter to allow the user to provide the user ID or name, followed by an optional reason.
- The **await ctx.guild.unban(member, reason=reason)** unbans the member from the server.

Don't forget to translate messages to your satisfaction.

Comment: @Chris there are just small changes between the codes, but you got a point

Comment: It's even more important to explain answers when the code changes are small :-). Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems alright just formatting issues.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} sunucudan atıldı.")
```

I suggest reading through the docs more carefully as its pretty basic mistakes you made. Have a look [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=ctx%20send) and try and learn the basics first before getting to the harder stuff.